# Use custom locale in Pop!OS

Tags: pop-os

### The issue

In the Pop!OS GUI, one can only set all locale settings at once. Date format, time format, paper format, number format, etc, are all selected with the country. Though not shown, I assume other things are included too, such as which is the first day of the week, what is the first week of the year, etc.

From the offerings, unfortunately there is none that fits my needs (I'm not difficult, I just know what I want ;)). **Therefore, I'm trying to set the locale myself**, which is what I need help with.

### What I've tried sofare

I've created my [own](https://github.com/rwijtvliet/dotfiles/blob/main/locale/en_ZZ) locale file and installed it as described [here](https://askubuntu.com/a/162714/271822) (from: "Installing your custom locale"). It seems to work; `date` for example on the command line shows the current datetime in the format I specified.

My question now is, **how can I get Pop!OS to use this configuration?** I cannot select/find it from the list in the regional settings:

[image]

I can see it's not being used from the am/pm time format in the top bar.